# Eclipse external null annotations for Kotlin

Tags: eclipse, kotlin-null-safety

for null-safety in Java, Eclipse has the org.eclipse.jdt.annotations.
In addition there is the EEA, the Eclipse external null annotations. They allow you to annotate with @NonNull/@Nullable for libraries where you cannot modify the code.

Now when using Kotlin and inter-operating with Java libs, how can i tell to Kotlin that the return value of a method is non-null or not?
I want to do define it once for such a lib signature, not everytime when i call to this API.

Is there an EEA like mechanism, or can i make Kotlin to understand the existing EEA files i have already?

regards
Frank